# SELECT TOP in this subqueries

Tags: sql

I am learning SELECT TOP from a SQL book, the author wrote this below query to return the number of order by state of the top 10 states:

```
SELECT state, numorders
FROM (SELECT TOP 20 o.state, COUNT(*) as numorders 
      FROM orders o
      GROUP BY o.state
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 ) summary
ORDER BY numorders desc
```

I did not understand his query, I wrote this one and this query returns the same result:

```
SELECT TOP 20 o.state, COUNT(*) as numorders 
FROM orders o
GROUP BY o.state
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

I am not sure but I thought there are reasons that the author wrote the 1st query like that ( which he did not explain in his book) Can someone help explain to me why? Which query should I go for? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The queries are equivalent, and an optimiser will likely result in the same thing being executed behind the covers.

I have a good inclination to think that the author is demonstrating the composability aspects of relational algebra. His version is taking a query, and then composing it with the outer select...order by. This is a powerful feature in relational algebra where complex sets can be built up of simpler ones. A sql optimiser in any decent implementation (e.g. sql server, oracle, etc.) will reduce the query to the most optimal path, so you are free to write queries in understandable, composable fashion, while not paying the penalty of additional operations. This is in fact a very powerful attribute of relational algebra.